# Sending a response to HTTP POST made by a third-party

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, response

I'm working with a third-party who are posting information via HTTP POST to a .NET site I host locally. The POST is successful but I need to have the site send a success/failure response to the POST.

I have looked around but have been unable to find any suggestions to meet this need.

Please let me know if I can further clarify anything.

Thank you.

Edit: To include the code.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["id"])  )
                { 
                    /* Populate the variables with the POST data
                     * Check first that the data is not empty or null */
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["id"]))
                    { leadID = nvc["id"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["FN"]))
                    { fn = nvc["FN"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["LN"]))
                    { ln = nvc["LN"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["EMAIL"]))
                    { email = nvc["EMAIL"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["PHONE"]))
                    { phone = nvc["PHONE"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["ADDRESS"]))
                    { address = nvc["ADDRESS"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["CITY"]))
                    { city = nvc["CITY"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["STATE"]))
                    { state = nvc["STATE"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["ZIP"]))
                    { zip = nvc["ZIP"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GENDER"]))
                    { gender = nvc["GENDER"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["BIRTHDAY"]))
                    { birthday = nvc["BIRTHDAY"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["TB"]))
                    { tobacco = nvc["tobacco"]; }                    

                  //  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["PPCSource"]))
                  //  { PPCSource = nvc["PPCSource"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GC_Source"]))
                    { GC_Source__c = nvc["GC_Source"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GC_Medium"]))
                    { GC_Medium__c = nvc["GC_Medium"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GC_Term"]))
                    { GC_Term__c = nvc["GC_Term"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GC_Content"]))
                    { GC_Content__c = nvc["GC_Content"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GC_Campaign"]))
                    { GC_Campaign__c = nvc["GC_Campaign"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GC_Custom_Segment"]))
                    { GC_Custom_Segment__c = nvc["GC_Custom_Segment"]; }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["GC_Num_of_Visits"]))
                    { GC_Num_of_Visits__c = nvc["GC_Num_of_Visits"]; }

                    googleCookie = "Source: " + GC_Source__c + "; Medium: " + GC_Medium__c + "; Term: " + GC_Term__c + "; Content: " + GC_Content__c + "; Camp: " + GC_Campaign__c + "; Segment: " + GC_Custom_Segment__c + "; Visits: " + GC_Num_of_Visits__c;

                    GC_Source__c = "PPCSource";                        

                    if (ln != null & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ln))
                    {
                        /* Call SetClientFunction with the POST Parameters Passed */
                        string result = SetClient(leadID, fn, ln, email, phone, address,city, state, zip, gender, birthday, tobacco, PPCSource, googleCookie, 0, GC_Source__c, GC_Medium__c, GC_Term__c);
                        SendNotice(GC_Source__c, fn, ln, result);
                    }
```

Comment: If you are handling the request, you can set the response status code to 200 OK (or any other code that makes sense for the scenario)

Comment: I would say that if you're already running a .NET site that's handling HTTP POSTs, it's probably _already_ providing some sort of response, as you'd have had to engineer it specifically to not provide one, so it's a little unclear as to what you're asking.

Comment: The feedback I have received from my third party is that they are timing out after they POST. While this application accepts POSTs it does not appear to be providing any response. My question is how to send a response, rather than have the site time out, even though it is posting successfully to my server.

Comment: And does your code run, and successfully do something with the data it receives?  Can we see your code?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see the code. Furthermore, I have an SMTP response set up to notify me if the POST was successful or a failure. The SMTP is working perfectly. Sorry, I should have included the code. I just can't seem to figure out how to paste the code without it being too long for this text box.

Comment: Edit it into your question, rather than putting it into a comment